# Bluetooth connection: python and raspberry pi

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I wouldlike to send some data from RTL2832 by bluetooth on python with my raspberry PI to my smartphone ( I use blueterm). The problem is actually my connexion is strange:
I want to run my script from my smartphone after connexion. Actually, if I want to get data, I need to connect my smartphone to my raspberry PI, then run script then disconnect the smartphone and finally reconnect the smartphone. I don't understand why I need to disconnect my smartphone for running the script...

Source : http://blog.davidvassallo.me/2014/05/11/android-linux-raspberry-pi-bluetooth-communication/

Thanks for any help

analyseur.py:

```
from pylab import*
from rtlsdr import*
from bluetooth import*
import sys

#configure device
sdr= RtlSdr()
sdr.sample_rate=double(sys.argv[3])
sdr.gain=double(sys.argv[2])
sdr.center_freq=double(sys.argv[1])

#Bluetooth connection

server_sock=BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)
server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)

port=server_sock.getsockname()[1]
uuid="94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"
client_sock,client_info=server_sock.accept()

while(1):
        samples=sdr.read_samples(256*1024)
        result=psd(samples,NFFT=1024, Fs=sdr.sample_rate/1e6, Fc=sdr.center_freq*1e6/1e6)

        client_sock.send(str(result[0]) // PXX value
        client_sock.send(str(result[1]) // Freq value
```